# Dynamic input fields are not displaying proper after selecting the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an add more button. Once the user clicks on it then it will display the select dropdown which is dynamic.

Now my issue is, after displaying the select drop-down there is one select dropdown which is called as `status`. If you choose from the status select dropdown then according to option input filed will display. But it displaying only once. If I click on add more button again and choose from the status dropdown then it's hiding the first one. I need to display both.

My expected output is,

```
id 2 | first dropdown | second dropdown | input field
id 3 | first dropdown | second dropdown | input field
id 4 | first dropdown | second dropdown | input field
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

  var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  a = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      a++;
      //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info" data-id="' + inner(a, 2) + '"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
  });



  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
  });

  // increment==============================================
  function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /* 
        return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
  }

});


$(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {
  //alert($(this).val());
  $(".input-wrapper").remove();
  if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '1')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else if (($('.pp_fileStatus').val() == '2')) {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
  } else {
    $(event.target).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Time</label><input type="text" name="time[]"  class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

  }
});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
  width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
  width: 100%;
}

.bankLink {
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="click_partner"> <input type="button" name="parner" value="Add More"></div>
  <div class="dynamicform">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- Link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k51p7z6q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this event handler:

```
$(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {
```

You don't refer to the current elements but to the global elements having some attribute. For example:

```
$(".input-wrapper").remove();
```

The previous line needs to turned into:

```
 $(this).closest('.row').find('div.input-wrapper').remove();
```

...and so on:

```js
var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
a = 1;
$(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        a++;
        //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info" data-id="' + inner(a, 2) + '"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="" selected>Choose</option> <option value="">Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control pp_fileStatus"><option disabled="" selected>Status</option> <option value="1">Status one</option><option value="2">Status two</option><option value="3">Status Three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
});


$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
});

// increment==============================================
function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /*
     return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
}
$(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function (event) {
$(this).closest('.row').find('div.input-wrapper').remove();
if (($(this).val() == '1')) {
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
} else if (($(this).val() == '2')) {
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Date</label><input type="text" name="reasonDate[]"  class="form-control datetimepicker"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Remark</label><input type="text" name="remark[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');
} else {
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Time</label><input type="text" name="time[]"  class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <label>Reason</label><input type="text" name="reason[]"  class="form-control"></div></div>');

}
});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
    width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
    width: 100%;
}

.bankLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">


<div class="container">
    <div class="click_partner"><input type="button" name="parner" value="Add More"></div>
    <div class="dynamicform">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: Yes, sure I will accept it and upvote you but after 4 min, because I am getting the warning from SO.